# How to overlap in react-native

Tags: react-native

Hi want to create UI in my react-native app like this

[image]

but I am getting like this

[image]

here is my code

```
<View style={{flex: 1,flexDirection:'row'}}>
            <View style={{flexDirection:'column',justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',alignSelf:'center'}}>
                <View style={{flex: 1,flexDirection:'row',alignItems:'flex-end',alignSelf:'flex-end',margin:10}}>
                    <Item style={{backgroundColor:AppColors.white,borderRadius:10,flexDirection:'column',height:100, width:100}}></Item>
                </View>
                <View style={{flex: 1,flexDirection:'row',alignItems:'flex-start',alignSelf:'flex-end',margin:10}}>
                    <Item style={{backgroundColor:AppColors.white,borderRadius:10,flexDirection:'column',height:100, width:100}}></Item>
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={{justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',alignSelf:'center'}}>
                <Item style={{backgroundColor:AppColors.colorPrimaryDark,
                    borderRadius:10,height:100, width:100, borderRadius:100/2}}></Item>
            </View>
            <View style={{flexDirection:'column',justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',alignSelf:'center'}}>
                <View style={{flex: 1,flexDirection:'row',alignItems:'flex-end',alignSelf:'flex-start',margin:10}}>
                    <Item style={{backgroundColor:AppColors.white,borderRadius:10,flexDirection:'column',height:100, width:100}}></Item>
                </View>
                <View style={{flex: 1,flexDirection:'row',alignItems:'flex-start',alignSelf:'flex-start',margin:10}}>
                    <Item style={{backgroundColor:AppColors.white,borderRadius:10,flexDirection:'column',height:100, width:100}}></Item>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[image]

You have have to use position:'absolute' and put the circle element as the last element of the elements list so it comes to top (no need to use zIndex).
also the container div must have styles for child elements to be centered. There won't be an issue since you can position that container div where ever you want.

Following code works as you expected. (I replaced 'Item' with 'View' and different colors. You can change those things back)

```
<View style={{flex: 1,flexDirection:'row', backgroundColor:'green', justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
                <View style={{flexDirection:'column',justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',alignSelf:'center'}}>
                    <View style={{flex: 1,flexDirection:'row',alignItems:'flex-end',alignSelf:'flex-end',margin:10}}>
                        <View style={{backgroundColor:'white',borderRadius:10,flexDirection:'column',height:100, width:100}}></View>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{flex: 1,flexDirection:'row',alignItems:'flex-start',alignSelf:'flex-end',margin:10}}>
                        <View style={{backgroundColor:'white',borderRadius:10,flexDirection:'column',height:100, width:100}}></View>
                    </View>
                </View>

                <View style={{flexDirection:'column',justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',alignSelf:'center'}}>
                    <View style={{flex: 1,flexDirection:'row',alignItems:'flex-end',alignSelf:'flex-start',margin:10}}>
                        <View style={{backgroundColor:'white',borderRadius:10,flexDirection:'column',height:100, width:100}}></View>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{flex: 1,flexDirection:'row',alignItems:'flex-start',alignSelf:'flex-start',margin:10}}>
                        <View style={{backgroundColor:'white',borderRadius:10,flexDirection:'column',height:100, width:100}}></View>
                    </View>
                </View>

                <View style={{justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',alignSelf:'center', position:'absolute'}}>
                    <View style={{backgroundColor:'blue',
                        borderRadius:10,height:100, width:100, borderRadius:100/2}}></View>
       </View>
</View>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer you saved my day working exactly how I want.

Colors are not an issue I will change it.