# How to set view relatively over another view in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to set half of the button over(above) the bottom edge of the card and half below the card. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545355/how-to-overlap-in-react-native

Comment: You should provide some code to show us what you get, what you try and if possible show us the desired output

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could share some more information, maybe some code you've tried, however use `position: "absolute"` in the style of the button.