# Overlapping items in React Native FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to make a list of items in `FlatList` overlap over each other like a stack of cards, but using a negative margin the item gets cut off, using "left: -20" does as well.

[image: Pic]

The image component is rather simple with round border:

```
export default class ProfilePicture extends React.Component {
  render () {
    let size = this.props.size || 50

    return (
      <Image
        source={{ uri: this.props.picture }}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(12, 94, 20, 0.5);',
          width: size,
          height: size,
          borderRadius: size / 2
        }}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

And in the list is where I try to accomplish the overlap:

```
export default class RidersListCompact extends Component {
  state = {
    users: []
  }

  ...

  renderItem = ({ item: user, index }) => {
    return <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
      <ProfilePicture
        picture={user.picture}
        size={Layout.window.hp(6)}
      />
    </View>
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <FlatList
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        data={this.state.users}
        keyExtractor={(user) => 'user_' + user.id}
        horizontal
        inverted
        style={{ ...styles.container, ...this.props.style }}

      />
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row-reverse'
  },
  itemContainer: {
    marginRight: -Layout.window.hp(2),
    width: Layout.window.hp(6),
    height: Layout.window.hp(6),
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0);'
  }
})
```

I tried setting different `zIndex` on each item but haven't had much luck, is there a way to overlap images/components in FlatList?

Cheers!

Comment: see this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545355/how-to-overlap-in-react-native

Comment: @Vivek: I've read through that before but I couldn't make it work in a FlatList. In a View that's no issue.

Comment: I think your image is containing a white background

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [Flex](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#flex). seperate Items by putting then in flex direact row wise. use Props from flex. Flex has following  props available

```
alignContent
alignItems
alignSelf
aspectRatio
borderBottomWidth
borderEndWidth
borderLeftWidth
borderRightWidth
borderStartWidth
borderTopWidth
borderWidth
bottom
direction
display
end
flex
flexBasis
flexDirection
flexGrow
flexShrink
flexWrap
height
justifyContent
left
margin
marginBottom
marginEnd
marginHorizontal
marginLeft
marginRight
marginStart
marginTop
marginVertical
maxHeight
maxWidth
minHeight
minWidth
overflow
padding
paddingBottom
paddingEnd
paddingHorizontal
paddingLeft
paddingRight
paddingStart
paddingTop
paddingVertical
position
right
start
top
width
zIndex
```

Comment: Thanks, I've done that for now using flexbox, but I can't wrap my head around how to make it work with FlatList, which I'd prefer to keep it useful when there's more items than what I can fit horizontally on the screen. I know I could get around it using ScrollView but I feel like there must be a better way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63464294/mapped-items-overlap-with-each-other Could you have a look here pls?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overlap images you should use position style in your styles. You need to set position to absolute and set left, right, top, bottom values.
[More information](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#position)